# Migration for many tables in one rows?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

My problem is now I have to remove 1 column that exists in almost tables in database.
I can handle it with basic migrations:

```
remove_column :table_1, :field_should_removed
remove_column :table_2, :field_should_removed
...
remove_column :table_n, :field_should_removed
```

But, is there any way to put all these table in one sentence like:

```
remove_column %i[table_1, table_2, ..., table_n], :field_should_removed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On way to do this with less code can be:

```
tables = %i[table_1, table_2, ..., table_n]
tables.each do |table|
  remove_column table, :field_should_removed
end
```

As you mentioned it is in most of the tables you may do like this too:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
  table_name = table.to_sym
  if column_exists?(table_name, :field_should_removed)
    remove_column table, :field_should_removed
  end
end
```